# unable to install oh my zsh using sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"

Tags: curl, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I tried installing oh my zsh using the command
`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`
but its giving the error
*curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75218 ms: Operation timed out*
I've tried installing it multiple times but I keep getting the same error.

I also tried using
`sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"`
and I get the error
*Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|2405:200:1607:2820:41::36|:443... failed: Operation timed out.
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|49.44.79.236|:443... failed: Operation timed out.*

I tried looking for a solution for the error *curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75218 ms: Operation timed out* but didn't find any solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gitee.com/mcornella/ohmyzsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).